# SFML Trying to shoot bullets but it moves with the gun

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm pretty new to SFML and C++ and I'm trying to figure out how to shoot bullets. I've done the shooting part and it's origin is from a moving shape controlled by the user called Player.

The problem is when I move, the origin moves as well which is why the bullets move with the origin. I feel like it's something really basic but I cannot for the life of me figure this out. Can anyone help?

This is the part of the code that creates and moves the shapes:

```
        //creates a new bullet when pressed
            else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Space)) {
            rects.push_back(sf::RectangleShape(sf::Vector2f(40, 10)));

        }
    }

    // clear the window with black color
    window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

    sf::Vector2f pl = player.getPosition();

    //draw active shapes in the vector and move them to the right
    for (int x = 0; x < rects.size(); x++)
    {
        rects[x].setOrigin(-pl.x,-(pl.y + 10));
        window.draw(rects[x]);
        rects[x].move(10, 0);   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If everything works just fine, and the only problem is origin changing after the bullet was shot - just move setting the origin on the line where it was initialized so that it is set only once and the time where it was shot:

```
 else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Space)) {
   sf::Vector2f pl = player.getPosition();
   sf::RectangleShape rect(sf::Vector2f(40, 10));
   rect.setOrigin(-pl.x,-(pl.y + 10));//not set pos?
   rects.push_back(rect);
 }
 // clear the window with black color
 window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

 //draw active shapes in the vector and move them to the right
 for (int x = 0; x < rects.size(); x++)
 {
   // Only move the rect here, don't set the origin.
   window.draw(rects[x]);
   rects[x].move(10, 0);   
 }
```